# Vue Pass Options to Plugin Loaded in Separate Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Setup: default vue-cli/webpack

Currently, I am using VueGoogleMaps in only one component, but I inject it globally in my app's main.js like so:

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
...
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
        key: 'bG9sdGhpc2lzbm90YW5hcGlrZXk=',
        libraries: 'places'
    }
});
```

I lazy load the only vue component using VueGoogleMaps, so I would like to import the plugin in that file instead of the entrypoint, to increase load speed when webpack does codesplitting.

How do I pass the options object (`{load:...}`) when importing it from a separate template? Typically I would do it like this:

```
components {
    VueGoogleMaps: () => import('vue2-google-maps')
}
```

But that doesn't prove me a way to pass in the options object.

Comment: try `import('vue2-google-maps').install(vue, options)`

Comment: VueGoogleMaps is a plugin in your code, not a component. Plugin should be attached to Vue before the main entry call and can not be loaded dynamically because it might change Vue prototype. You can see that it(version 0.10.6) registers all components by itself in the source code. Yes, you can disabled it with installComponents=false but there is still no way for code-splitting because plugin already imported all components in its main.js(even if it does not install it).

Comment: @MaxSinev you're right, I was conflating plugins and components. Word today involves a brief excursion into media query hell, but when I'm done that I'll give Evgeni's suggestion try